# "In spite of both" vs. "in spite both of"

Tags: word-usage, word-order

Which of the following two is correct usage:

> They managed to cross the border *in spite of **both*** the barbed wire and the border patrol agents.

Or,

> They managed to cross the border *in spite **both** of* the barbed wire and of the border patrol agents.

Answer (score 1):

The first is more natural, but even there "both" isn't really needed. And "in spite of" is better as "despite". So a modified first sentence could be

> They managed to cross the border despite the barbed wire and the patrols.

Comment: So, you are saying that both of them are grammatically correct, but the first one is just used more. Am I correct?

Comment: No, the second isn't so good: "both of the barbed wire" seems like there are two sets of barbed wire. Drop that one and focus on improving the first.